# Complements in grammar, may they seem like objects?

Tags: sentence-construction, complements

> He seemed hasty.

Is *hasty* a complement, perhaps a verb complement, to *seemed*? There is no noun in the object position. May *hasty* be understood as an object here, to get a complete sentence?

Comment: Would you please ask a question about what the verb *seem* means and when to use it in a sentence? And how *seem* is different from *is*? Because you need to understand this concept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An *object* is a kind of *complement*—a piece of the sentence which "completes" the meaning of the verb. A "complete sentence" does not necessarily require either an *object* (a Direct Object or Indirect Object) or any other kind of *complement*; it depends on what verb is employed.

Some verbs require at least one object. We call these *transitive*, from Latin *transire*, "go across", because the action of the verb "goes across" to the object: the object "receives" the action. Some of these take both an object *and* a complement; *appoint*, for instance, and *make* in some of its many senses:

> The president appointed [<sup>DIRECT OBJECT</sup>him] [<sup>COMPLEMENT</sup>professor].
>   Brian made [<sup>DIRECT OBJECT</sup>me] [<sup>COMPLEMENT</sup>really angry].

With these verbs, the complement is usually a nominal which identifies the object or an adjectival which describes it.

Other verbs, which we call *intransitive*, do not require an object. Some of these, like *be*, *become*, *seem* require a complement, which is usually a nominal which identifies the *subject* or an adjectival which describes it.

> He is angry.
>   He has become a prominent man.

Others, however, do not require even a complement; verbs like *run* and *talk* designate activities which are self-contained.

> He is running.
>   He talked for several minutes.

Note that many verbs have both transitive and intransitive senses. *Run*, for instance, is intransitive in the sentence above; but it may also be used transitively, as when we speak of *running a marathon* or *running a company*.

Comment: I guess I maybe thought a "complete sentence" contained a noun. I guess I thought nouns seem objects, direct or maybe indirect. In "Brian made me really angry". Brian (subject?), made (verb [transitive]?), me (noun, object?), I don't think that may get a complete sentence, maybe, so, angry (adjective [complement]?), (adjectival complement[?])

I maybe used an intransitive verb? "He seemed hasty" seems a complete sentence.

Comment: @saySay This is very complicated, particularly if your own language does things differently. Think of it this way: A "complete sentence" consists of  **1) a verb**. This may be one word or many, as in "was going" or "has been going".  **2)** the verb's **arguments**. These are the specific pieces which that particular verb requires. Different verbs require different numbers of arguments, of different kinds; and those arguments, again, may be single words or very long phrases. But all verbs require at least one argument: **2a) a subject**. (... *continuing* ... )

Comment: The subject is a "nominal", a word or set of words which plays the role of a noun. A nominal may be a single noun, or a noun with its modifiers, or a pronoun, or even a *clause*: a kind of sub-sentence which cannot stand by itself. **2b)** Many verbs have more arguments; these are called **complements**. Complements which "receive" the "action" of the verb are called **objects**, and these, too, are nominals. But there are many complements which are not objects; some of these are nominals, others are "adjectivals" (which are adjectives, or act like it) or preposition phrases. (..*cont'd* ..)

Comment: I think I thought upon "He ran" ran 1) a verb, 2) argument of this verb, "He"? He, here, seems a pronoun so, maybe, a nominal. Interesting. I don't think I got anyone to aim to discern a complete sentence like this. I think this seems interesting. So, maybe, discerning like this, "He ran" may seem a complete sentence?

Comment: What you have to keep in mind is that each verb has its own set of complement types and meanings. Some very common verbs, with many different meanings, even have several *different* sets of complements, depending on which  meaning is intended. . . . So in the end you can't just say that a complete sentence consists of Subject-Verb-Object (which is only true sometimes) or that Subjects and Objects are nouns (which is only true in the simplest sentences) -- you have to know the entire range of arguments which each verb requires to analyze the sentence correctly.

Comment: @saySay Yes, you've got it! *He ran* is a complete sentence, because the only argument *run* requires when it means "move very fast with long strides" is a Subject.

Comment: And in *Brian made me angry* the verb *made* takes 3 arguments: Subject (*Brian*), Object (*me*) and Object Complement (*really angry*), an adjective phrase -- we call it *Object* Complement because it describes the Object. This means "Brian caused me to become angry". Without the Object Complement (*Brian made me*) it would mean something completely different: "Brian caused me to exist".

Comment: This seems interesting! It seems interesting to discern it like this!

Comment: @saySay Does it only *seem* interesting, or *is* it interesting?

Comment: Hello, StoneyB. May you place here where you got this information? May you place here grammar books you may have got this from, and, or, read?